# Absolute or relative path to a connected LAN computer for code to save file automatically on the LAN Computer

Tags: mac, ssh, lan, remote

I have a mac mini and an old mac that are connected via ethernet cable. From my mac mini, I can ssh into the old mac in the terminal using ssh username.

I have a python code in my mac mini that generates data, and I want it to be sent over to the old mac machine. Is there like a absolute or relative path from my mac mini to old mac, that I can use in my code to direct where to save the data file? 
I want to skip the burden of transferring the data files manually every time.

If there is any other way of doing this code wise, please let me know! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You mention ssh and python, so here's an approach...

1) Generate ssh key on old Mac as the user your code runs as and setup to allow auto-login, etc.
2) Install the [paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/) lib for ssh via python.
3) Using said libs, deposit data files to whatever path on the old Mac you'd like.

If you just want to copy to a path, there a insecure ways via NFS or the like, but using paramiko is so easy to keep everything secure.